# Can not align dropdown menu along the length of the page

Tags: html, css

I need to align dropdown menu along the length of the page. I have a menu :

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
        <li><a href="#">About the company</a>
            <img src="images/arr1.png" ></img>
            <ul>
                <li class="first_li"><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Vacancy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Best Experts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

Then I have some css styles to make this dropdown menu to be align in as I thougth right manner.But it doesn't work correctly.

```
.menu li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    line-height:84px;
}


.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block; 
    background-color: rgb(231,231,231);
    position:absolute;
    top:84px;
    left : 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    z-index:1;
}

.menu .language:hover > ul {
    display:block; 
    width:84px;
    line-height:30px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of this?

Comment: @JonH Really? You populated html and css areas with html code.

Comment: That was a mistake I performed an update: http://jsfiddle.net/z2ycjgj5/4/

Comment: What you mean with "along the length of the page"? If what you want is to display the items vertically then remove the attribute float: left to li.

Comment: @ADASein I mean that I want to display the items horisontally in a line

Comment: The items are showing up the way you want it.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/g1cjgy1m/6/)

Comment: @ADASein if you will look at my last added link to the jsfiddle, you will see that items are not located in the way I want it

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem looks like you have most of your list style in the 'hover' part. Try putting that into the general menu style.